# How to show the text in the middle of the li tag?

Tags: html, css

I have a list of images in **ul** and **li** tags that I want to show their names on them, just in the middle of the **li** tag.

I use the **absolute position** for the **span** tag to overlay the **img** tag, but the texts will not appear inside the **li** and it causes to set **"left"** for each of the **span** tangs separately so each one of them will be adjusted in the middle of their own image. How can I fix the problem?

```css
.div1 {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
.div_1 {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  display: inline;
}
.img_1 {
  text-align: center;
}
span.s1,
span.s2,
span.s3,
span.s4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1 div_1">
  <div>
    <img class="img_1" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /><span class="s1">TEXT</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /><span class="s2">TEXT</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /><span class="s3">TEXT</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /><span class="s4">TEXT</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited some part of your css.

The main changes concern `LI` element.

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
```

LI have both to behave like `block` and `inline` elements (though you can use `float` property instead). `position` is set to `relative` so absolute-positionned elements inside will be positionned *relatively* to their parents.

About `span` elements :

```
span.s1,
span.s2,
span.s3,
span.s4 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 45%;
  left: 0%;
  width:100%;
}
```

`bottom` set to 45% will place them slightly above the vertical middle. `left` set to `0%` and width to `100%` is meant to place the text in the middle (not sure if it works this way on all browsers.

Moreover, I think that this piece of code could be improved to avoid these tricks.

```css
.div1 {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
.div_1 {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
span.s1,
span.s2,
span.s3,
span.s4 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 45%;
  left: 0%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1 div_1">
  <div>
    <img class="img_1" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /><span class="s1">TEXT</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /><span class="s2">TEXT</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /><span class="s3">TEXT</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /><span class="s4">TEXT</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I did the following:

```
li {
  position:relative;
}
```

When using absolute position its important to use relative position on the parent to contain it correctly.

I found a good article here as well for you:

- https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Answer (score 2):

Give following css.

Use `position: relative;` to `li` and give `display:inline-block` instead of `display:inline`.

And give `transform: translate(0px, -50%);` to `span` to make it proper center.

```css
.div1 {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
.div_1 {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.img_1 {
  text-align: center;
}
span.s1,
span.s2,
span.s3,
span.s4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10%;
  transform: translate(0px, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="div1 div_1">
  <div>
    <img class="img_1" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /><span class="s1">TEXT</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /><span class="s2">TEXT</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /><span class="s3">TEXT</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /><span class="s4">TEXT</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Kindly see below updated code:

```
.div1 {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
.div_1 {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
    position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.img_1 {
  text-align: center;
}
span.s1,
span.s2,
span.s3,
span.s4 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0px;
  top: 35%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This will make your code in centre as desired

Comment: Please add a working snippet to your answer for ease of use and to gain points; this is cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap each element inside a `<li>` in a `<div style = "position:relative">`

```css
.div1 {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
.div_1 {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.img_1 {
  text-align: center;
}
span.s1,
span.s2,
span.s3,
span.s4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1 div_1">
  <div>
    <img class="img_1" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div style="position:relative">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /><span class="s1">TEXT</span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div style="position:relative">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /><span class="s2">TEXT</span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div style="position:relative">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /><span class="s3">TEXT</span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div style="position:relative">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /><span class="s4">TEXT</span>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just set `position: relative;` on `li` instead of using extra elements and unnecessary inline-CSS?